# insertar valor de un input a una funcion url

Tags: javascript, api

Estoy haciendo un pequeño formulario donde solo capturo un numero, luego este debe ser insertado en una funcion que contiene una url (API), para despues mostrar la informacion json que contiene.
No he logrado aún que se renozca el valor dentro de la url

```
 function buscar() {
      let trck = document.getElementById("iptTrack").value;
         if (trck =="") {
          alert("no has ingreso numero")      
           }else{
             alert(track);
              document.getElementById("iptTrack").value="";   
  }
}


var contenido = document.querySelector('#contenido')
    function traer() {
     fetch('"https://api.pactrak.com/ibcairbill/track/".$trck/ ')
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(data => {
      console.log(data.status['0'].consignee_name)
      contenido.innerHTML = `
      <p>nombre: ${data.status['0'].consignee_name}</p>`
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. El alcance de la variable trck no está de forma global
2. En el fetch la concatenación y string es incorrecto, igualmente el nombre de la variable.

Defina let trck = null; por fuera de la función , borre el let de trck , construya el link de fetch con string templates (con las comillas francesas alt + 96 , encerrar todo el string) [https://api.pactrak.com/ibcairbill/track/${trck}/](https://api.pactrak.com/ibcairbill/track/$%7Btrck%7D/)